# VBA Expression TimeSpan.Duration HH:MM

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

How can I modify the following expression to display in the format HH:MM? This is for a .rdlc report.

```
=System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TotalEstimated.Value)).Duration
```

I was expecting a .Duration.Hours, but nothing there.

Thanks

Comment: this is VB.NET not VBA. `.Duration`, according to MSDN, returns a new TimeSpan struct so Hours should be there, as you say. Strange. Is the overload `.ToString(String format)` method there? You could use that.

Comment: When you say it's not there, do you mean it simply doesn't show up in IntelliSense, or that you get an error if you try running the report with it in there?

Comment: Long after the event, but to explain Adrian's point, IntelliSense doesn't always show everything that you can access on an object (I have never looked in to why). Always check the object's methods in MSDN / Help Viewer / Object browser if you can't see something you expect in IntelliSense, then just type it out manually. It should compile fine.